# Running a fyne/golang test job, error with dependencies

Tags: go, dependencies, dependency-properties, goland, fyne

I am running a trial example, it gives an error.
Some kind of problem with dependencies.

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("Fyne Demo")
    label := widget.NewLabel("Hello, Fyne!")
    content := container.NewVBox( label, )
    myWindow.SetContent(content)
    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}
```

error:

```
go build github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.2-core/gl:

# pkg-config --cflags  -- gl gl

Package gl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gl.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'gl' found Package gl was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gl' found
pkg-config: exit status 1

# github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw

In file included from ./glfw/src/internal.h:188,
from ./glfw/src/context.c:30,
from ../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw@v0.0.0-20221017161538-93cebf72946b/c_glfw.go:4:
./glfw/src/x11_platform.h:33:10: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
```

PS libgl1, libglu1 - installed

sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev mesa-common-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libglu1-mesa-dev
E: Unable to locate package mesa-common-dev

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need development headers, the command is distro specific, you can see at https://developer.fyne.io/started/.

If you are Debian/Ubuntu then it’s `sudo apt-get install golang gcc libgl1-mesa-dev xorg-dev`.
This is just for development of course, the compiled app will work without any of this installed.